# Removing double quotes present inside string

Tags: bash, sed

I want to remove double quotes present inside the string so when I use double quotes as a separator it will not give extra columns.

For example:

Input:

```
"t3_2qys9a","YamahaR","\"The thing wouldn't shut so I screwed it shut.\" That's when I said in my head, \"There was a recall for this from ford, Sachin.\"", "Justrolledintothesho"
```

Output:

```
"t3_2qys9a", "YamahaR", "The thing wouldn't shut so I screwed it shut. That's when I said in my head, There was a recall for this from ford, Sachin.", "Justrolledintothesho"
```

I tried with sed but it removes all the double quotes from it.

```
cat sample.txt | sed 's/\"/""
```

Comment: You first state you want to remove `","`, but then show an example that removes `\"` and some `,` (and adds some spaces). Can you clarify what it is you are trying to do ?

Comment: Sorry for that I was posting two questions so it became a mixup of that I want to remove double quotes here. I will edit it. Thanks

Comment: I assume the added spaces (eg. `"t3_2qys9a", "` instead of `"t3_2qys9a","`) are also accidental ? If so, are you simply looking for a global delete of `\"` ?

Comment: Please use less offensive text as examples; the automated detectors for rude behaviour tripped on your post. Just use "Mary has a little lamb" or something.

Comment: Your output has added a space after the first two `,` which separate the fields. Is it your intent to have that included in the sed operation?

Comment: Someone else has edited it. It was not my intention

Comment: While other people have edited, the extra spaces after the two `,` were in the [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58389300/1) ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/f568a90f-85b3-4c87-a100-de99d9be091b/view-source)). You can [see all revisions here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58389300/revisions). Please [edit] to correct, if you did not intend those to be there.

Comment: Wrong approach imo. Your input is perfectly fine if read with right csv tools. It uses quotechar and escapechar. Find the good tool to read this proper input instead of trying to "fix" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the added spaces after the comma's are accidental, this should remove all escaped double quotes from the file :

```
sed 's/\\\"//g' sample.txt
```

Comment: @RaviSaroch : sure - it doesn't hurt though, and imo is clearer.

Comment: I am just little curious that why "double" or "Triple" backslash does not going to effect the result.

Comment: I would say it less clearer to use an unneeded backslash.  Its enough to escape it once.  So  use `sed 's/\\"//g'`